# Class Object Error 'Undefined Reference For'

Tags: algorithm, oop, c++11

I get the following error when calling the class object and functions in a class instance:

**1) fig7_17.cpp:**

```
fig07_17.cpp

#include <array>
#include "GradeBook.h" 
using namespace std;

// function main begins program execution
int main()
{
   
   const array< int, GradeBook::students > grades = 
      { 87, 68, 94, 100, 83, 78, 85, 91, 76, 87 }; 
   string courseName = "CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming";

   GradeBook myGradeBook( courseName, grades );
   myGradeBook.displayMessage();
   myGradeBook.processGrades(); 
}
```

**2) Gradebook.cpp :**

```
// Fig. 7.16: GradeBook.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "GradeBook.h" 
using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook( const string &name, 
   const array< int, students > &gradesArray )
   : courseName( name ), grades( gradesArray )
{
} 

void GradeBook::setCourseName( const string &name )
{
   courseName = name; 
} 


string GradeBook::getCourseName() const
{
   return courseName;
} 
void GradeBook::displayMessage() const
{
   cout<< "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" 
      << endl;
} 

void GradeBook::processGrades() const
{
   // output grades array
   outputGrades();

   // call function getAverage to calculate the average grade
   cout << setprecision( 2 ) << fixed; 
   cout << "\nClass average is " << getAverage() << endl;

   // call functions getMinimum and getMaximum
   cout << "Lowest grade is " << getMinimum() << "\nHighest grade is "
      << getMaximum() << endl;

   // call function outputBarChart to print grade distribution chart
   outputBarChart();
} // end function processGrades

int GradeBook::getMinimum() const
{
   int lowGrade = 100; // assume lowest grade is 100

   // loop through grades array
   for ( int grade : grades )
   {
      // if current grade lower than lowGrade, assign it to lowGrade
      if ( grade < lowGrade )
         lowGrade = grade; // new lowest grade
   } // end for

   return lowGrade; // return lowest grade
} // end function getMinimum


int GradeBook::getMaximum() const
{
   int highGrade = 0; // assume highest grade is 0

   // loop through grades array
   for ( int grade : grades )
   {
      // if current grade higher than highGrade, assign it to highGrade
      if ( grade > highGrade )
         highGrade = grade; // new highest grade
   } // end for

   return highGrade; // return highest grade
} // end function getMaximum     

// determine average grade for test
double GradeBook::getAverage() const
{
   int total = 0; // initialize total

   // sum grades in array
   for ( int grade : grades )
      total += grade;

   // return average of grades
   return static_cast< double >( total ) / grades.size();
} // end function getAverage


void GradeBook::outputBarChart() const
{
   cout << "\nGrade distribution:" << endl;

   // stores frequency of grades in each range of 10 grades
   const size_t frequencySize = 11;
   array< unsigned int, frequencySize > frequency = {}; // init to 0s

   // for each grade, increment the appropriate frequency
   for ( int grade : grades )
      ++frequency[ grade / 10 ];

   
   for ( size_t count = 0; count < frequencySize; ++count ) 
   {
      // output bar labels ("0-9:", ..., "90-99:", "100:" )
      if ( 0 == count )
         cout << "  0-9: ";
      else if ( 10 == count )
         cout << "  100: ";
      else
         cout << count * 10 << "-" << ( count * 10 ) + 9 << ": ";
      
      // print bar of asterisks
      for ( unsigned int stars = 0; stars < frequency[ count ]; ++stars )
         cout << '*';

      cout << endl; // start a new line of output
   } 
} 


void GradeBook::outputGrades() const
{
   cout << "\nThe grades are:\n\n";

   // output each student's grade
   for ( size_t student = 0; student < grades.size(); ++student )
      cout << "Student " << setw( 2 ) << student + 1 << ": " << setw( 3 )
         << grades[ student ] << endl;
}
```

**3) GradeBook.h:**

```
#include <string> 
#include <array>

class GradeBook
{
public:
   // constant -- number of students who took the test
   static const size_t students = 10; // note public data

   // constructor initializes course name and array of grades
   GradeBook( const std::string &, const std::array< int, students > & );

   void setCourseName( const std::string & ); 
   std::string getCourseName() const; 
   void displayMessage() const;
   void processGrades() const; 
   int getMinimum() const;  
   int getMaximum() const; 
   double getAverage() const; 
   void outputBarChart() const;
   void outputGrades() const; 
private:
   std::string courseName; 
   std::array< int, students > grades; 
};
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\cciKxoUd.o:fig07_17.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `GradeBook::GradeBook(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::array<int, 10u> const&)'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\cciKxoUd.o:fig07_17.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `GradeBook::displayMessage() const'
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\cciKxoUd.o:fig07_17.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `GradeBook::processGrades() const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 330ms]
```

I may have used wrong terms because I did not understand some situations. But I fixed it. I'm sorry. I think the written code is correct. I use sublime text by the way.

I tried to access the class members and functions but I got a error.(how to program C++ - Exeample 7_15_17)

Comment: You have a linking error, not a compile time error. How did you compile and link this? Please provide the exact commands. Did you perhaps forget to compile a `.cpp` file or link with the resulting object file? Please also post your error message as _text_, not as a picture.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post the text instead. That makes it easier to (hint!!) search the error online. Also, nobody here knows what you did, in particular what code you wrote and how you tried to compile it. Provide a [mcve] along with the according instructions.

Comment: I looked into it before, but it didn't help much. @RaymondChen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400 "Commonly, each translation unit will generate an object file that contains the definitions of the symbols defined in that translation unit. To use those symbols, you have to link against those object files." The linker is saying "I can't find `GradeBook::GradeBook`." Did you remember to give it GradeBook::GradeBook?

Comment: I looked at the link you gave, but I got an error for some reason I don't understand. I always compile with IDE. I have never tried it from the terminal so I have no knowledge. I wrote the following code and it worked: 
 g++ -o program_gradebook GradeBook.cpp figure7_17.cpp.
Yes, you were right. There was a linking error. @TedLyngmo .  So thank u all for your answer.

Comment: @faikmermer Ok, nice, in that case I suspect that `GradeBook.cpp` is not added to the IDE project. Both `figure7_17.cpp ` and `GradeBook.cpp` must show up if you list the files included in the project from within the IDE. It's not enough that they are in the same directory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i imported the files into the IDE but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you make the IDE show the exact commands it uses when compiling and linking your program? If so, copy that output and include it exactly as it is in the question so that we can see what it looks like.